# Telegram API.AI payment integration

Tags: json, stripe-payments, telegram, telegram-bot, dialogflow-es

My query is related to integrating Telegrams Payment feature.

Here is my setup: **Telegram (mybot) <–> API.AI (agent) <–> webhook (google app engine)**. The webhook on google app engine picks some requested information from web and send back to API.AI.

Given this setup I have following questions:

1. As per the Telegram Payment API documentation, one needs to send **sendInvoice()** message to the telegram bot for initiating the payment process. How to send this message from API.AI ? Should I use **custom payload** option ? if yes, what should be the format of json data to send ? (refer end of the questions for the formats that i tried without any success)
2. Telegram sends the final confirmation of the transaction in the form of an **Update** with the field *pre_checkout_query*, how to handle this in API.AI ? Will the API.AI platform interpret this response or should I have a specific intent in API.AI to handle this data from Telegram?
3. As the final step in completion of Payment procedure, how to send back **answerPreCheckoutQuery**() message from API.AI ? I am assuming this would be a custom payload, what should be the format of json data ?

Here is the json format I tried for **sendInvoice** option in API.AI **custom payload**:

```
{
“telegram”: {
“InvoiceConfig”:{
“title”:“test invoice title”,
“description”:“test description”,
“payload” : “Payload”,
"provider_token" : "111111:TEST:abcd1234",
“start_parameter”:“my_unique_start_parameter”,
“currency”:“usd”,
“prices”: [{“label” : “registration”,“amount” : 300},{“label” : “consultation”,“amount” : 200}]
}
}
}
```

Changed **InvoiceConfig** to **Invoice, invoice, sendInvoice** etc without success. Telegram doesn’t render the response.
***provider_token*** is Stripe Test Payment Token.

[Link to Telegram Payment API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#payments)

PS: With a stand alone Python script I was able to successfully perform the payment integration however I had no breakthrough when using API.AI